# CSS using :not selector and borders

Tags: google-chrome, css, css-selectors

I have some CSS like so:

```css
table.varTabs th
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: #637356 2px solid;   
}

table.varTabs th.active
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: #637356 0px solid;
}
```

This is used in my table to show and hide borders under my th (which are tabs at the top of the table).  So in Firefox, it works correctly that when active is in the class, the bottom border that it gets from the base css, gets removed. But my Chrome version isn't happening that way.

How do I use CSS to select the table.varTabs th that don't have active in the class? (I want a CSS approach and not JQuery or adding a unactive class in the HTML).

In Chrome (not correct): http://screencast.com/t/sqJfWS6S
In Firefox (correct): http://screencast.com/t/kXPHPV6Hyao

See the line under use variables.

Comment: Your screen shot looks like the border under the active tab would be coming from the lower div, not from the tab.  Did you look in Chrome's debugger what is says is the value for border on both tab and main area?

Comment: In chrome debugger the lower div has border-left, right and bottom only

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer instead.

Comment: @chris can you show all your css code regarding to your table element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there is a Chrome bug somehow, I did this and it worked:

```
table.varTabs th
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: #637356 2px solid;   
}

table.varTabs th.active
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-bottom: #fff 2px solid;
}
```

Created a white border to overwrite the other one on a white background.

Answer (score 2):

`table.varTabs th:not(.active)`

But this should only work under css3 supported environment

Answer (score 0):

You can target `table.varTabs th` in a CSS rule and then put the `table.varTabs th.active` rule after it to override whatever you want to change for the active class.  There is no need to use `:not` when doing it this way and it's compatible with very old browsers.

```
table.varTabs th {
   /* regular and default rules here */
}

table.varTabs th.active {
   /* .active override rules here */
}
```

Comment: Yea that's the way css usually should be

Comment: ummm how's that different then whay i have above

Comment: @chris - it's not different.  This is how you do it.  We can't help with the exact specifics of your issue without seeing actual HTML/CSS.  You may have some other issue that you haven't described causing the problem.

Comment: we'lll thats the CSS from the Chrome developer tools. Added screenshots.

Comment: @Chris - Perhaps you are seeing a difference in how border-collapse works in different browsers.  I don't think we can help much further without a working example in something like a jsFiddle.